# osx, mysql command goes in /var/empty

Tags: mysql, macos

I just installed mysql with homebrew on mac OSX.

The very first thing I did after the installation was the following symlink:
/usr/bin/mysql -> /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.15/bin/mysql

But if I type 'mysql', instead of having the mysql-client interface, I get into /var/empty/, exactly like if I was doing a cd /var/empty/

Why, and how can I fix this problem so that the mysql command execute the mysql client ?

Comment: Does your shell have a 'mysql' alias, perhaps, which is malfunctioning?

Comment: @Marc B.: I don't know, how may I check ?

Comment: To the person who voted for close: I'm setuping a brand new iMac, so it's not a specific/personnal case, and the FAQ specify "software tools commonly used by programmers", and I think that the Terminal and MySQL are tools commonly used by programmers.

Comment: 'alias' at the prompt would show any.

Comment: @Mark B. ➜  ~  alias | grep mysql return: 
mysql='nocorrect mysql'

Comment: Mark B. I've done an unalias mysql, and the symlink in is now working well. As you helped me to find the cause, I let you post an anwser ! ;)

Comment: @FMaz008 I tried the unalias but it doesn't work for me. Any way to permanently remove the alias mysql='nocorrect mysql'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does your shell have a 'mysql' alias, perhaps, which is malfunctioning? `alias` at the prompt will show any aliases that are set.

Answer (score 15):

This can occur if you're using zsh since it will drop you into a user's home directory just by typing their user name. So if mysql isn't in your path (which it wouldn't be since it's a keg only formula), but you have a mysql user, then this is the behavior you would see. You can force Homebrew to link mysql into your path with `brew link --force mysql55`.

Comment: for the newer versions of MySQL, just: "brew link --force mysql"

Comment: Thanks for this answer! My symlink had disappeared after I upgraded from Yosemite to El Capitan.

Comment: Neither are working. ╰─ brew link --force mysql                                                                                          1 ↵ 
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/mysql

Answer (score 0):

For Homebrew 3.2:

```
brew link mysql@5.7 --force
```

Of course if the installed version was 5.7.